# Suposse that U is a finite non empty subset of G and that it is closed under multiplication. Prove that U is a group.

Tags: group-theory

**Suppose that $U$ is a finite non empty subset of $G$ and that it is closed under multiplication. Prove that $U$ is a group.**

So if it is non empty and closed under multiplication all that is needed to do is to show that inverses exist in $U$? I know that is really simple but I am struggling with how to actually write it down.

**Next, if $U=\langle x\rangle$ and $n=|U|$, prove that $x^n=e$.**

Is is correct to say that since x generates the group the order of x is n and so $x^n=e$?

The question as a whole is 8 marks so I am struggling to formalise how to write it down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $x\in U$ and consider the set $A=\{x^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Verify that this is a subset of $U$. Why must $A$ be finite? If $A$ is finite, why does this imply that $e$ is in $A$ (use the fact that $A$ is a subset of the group $G$)? Can you say what the inverse of $x$ is once you know $A$ is finite?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take $x\in U$. Show that there exists such a $k$ that $x^k=e$. That means $x^{k-1}=x^{-1}.$

For the second question, you know that $U=\langle x\rangle = \{e,x,x^2,\dots,x^m\}$ for some $m$. Show that $m=n-1$ and show that if $x^n\neq e,$ then $|U|\neq n$.

Comment: how do i show that there exists such a k that $x^k$=e?

Comment: @ZZS14 Proof by contradiction. Remember, $G$ is finite!

Comment: i don't get it, I know it is true but i can't show it.

Comment: Yes, well, a common thing in mathematics is that you don't *get* things after one minute. Try to think what would happen if you take the sequence $x,x^2,x^3,\dots$. Since $U$ is finite, what can you say about this sequence?

Comment: it must terminate

Comment: Well, not exactly. For example, the sequence $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\dots$ does not terminate, it is infinite. For any natural value $n$, I can tell you the $n$-th value of the sequence.

Comment: at some point it repeats?

Comment: That is true. That means you have two elements which are equal. Write that down as an equation.

Comment: $x^k$=$x^j$ for some k,j

Comment: There you go. Now, say $k<j$. What happens if you multiply the equation by $(x^{k})^{-1}$?

Comment: do you get $x^jx^{-k}=1$

Comment: Sure, but you know the rules for calculating $a^m\cdot a^n$, don't you?

Comment: oh yeah so you've got $x^{j-k}$

Comment: Well, call it what you want. I will call it "elephant". $\text{elephant}=j-k$ is the number for which $x^{\text{elephant}} = e$.

Comment: okay, then is it enough to say that this means $x^{r-1}=x^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, $x^{-1}$ is by definition such an element that $x\cdot x^{-1} = e$. Does the element $x^{r-1}$ satisfy this demand?

Comment: yes! okay, got it. sorry I'm so slow! so I have proved that U is a group, now for the second part.

Comment: do you use the fact that |U|=n to say that m-1=n?

Comment: Yes. That is fairly trivial. The next part then follows from the fact that if $x^n\neq e$, then $x^n$ is another distinct element of $U$.